# ¿Por qué usaron la palabra "new" en este código?

Tags: c++

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string* titulos = NULL;
    string* autores = NULL;

    int tamanio ; //Se inicializa la variable

    cout << "Cuantos libros desea ingresar?";

    string entrada;

    getline(cin, entrada); //Se asigna el valor ingresado

    tamanio = stoi(entrada); //Se transforma la entrada en número

    titulos = new string[tamanio]; //Declaramos un arreglo del tamaño ingresado para los titulos
    autores = new string[tamanio]; //Declaramos un arreglo del tamaño ingresado para los autores

    cout << "Por favor ingrese la siguiente información de los Libros: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n******* Libro " << i + 1 << "********:\n";
        cout << "Titulo: ";
        //cin >> titulos[i]; //No funciona con espacios
        getline(cin, titulos[i]);
        cout << "Autor: ";
        //cin >> autores[i]; //No funciona con espacios
        getline(cin, autores[i]);
    }

    //Liberamos la memoria de ambos punteros
    delete [] titulos;
    delete [] autores;
    titulos = NULL;
    autores = NULL;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es **exactamente** la pregunta? De todo el código que has pegado ¿Qué es lo importante?

Comment: `new` es utilizado para reservar memoria, el cual a la hora de utilizarlo retorna un puntero que apunta a la región de la memoria reservada de acuerdo al tipo, ejemplo: `int* z = new int[1];` allí acabamos de reservar 4 bytes de memoria en arquitectura de 32 bits, y 8 bytes en la de 64 bits,  en el caso de `std::string` el cual es una clase, ocupa 4 bytes por cada x tamaño que reserves... de acuerdo a tu pregunta, usa `new` para manejar la memoria de forma mas dinámica, pero yo utilizaría `malloc();` y `realloc();` al estilo C para mas seguridad...

Answer (score 3):

¿Por qué usar `new` aquí?

```
string* titulos = NULL;
titulos = new string[tamanio];
// ...
delete[] titulos;
```

Están declarando un arreglo de cadenas de caracteres. El tamaño se determina en tiempo de ejecución y C++ no admite VLA (Variable Lenth Arrays o arrays de longitud variable), lo que hace que el siguiente código no sea legal en C++ (aunque algunos compiladores y extensiones lo permiten):

```
int tamanio;
std::cin >> tamanio;
string titulos[tamanio];
```

Por conocimiento o azar (apostaría por esta última) el que escribió el código decidió recurrir a la memoria dinámica para crear los arreglos.

Como bien he dicho, yo apostaría a que lo hizo así por azar, ya que en caso contrario muy seguramente habría recurrido a los contenedores:

```
std::vector<std::string> titulos(tamanio);
// ...
// no hace falta delete alguno
```

Comment: Lo vi en una pagina donde ponian ejemplos de usos de punteros, quiza sea eso